# Permission issues running Firefox via xvfb - seems to be referencing root

Tags: permissions, firefox, xvfb

I'm trying to run Firefox via xvfb on a remote VPS. However I'm running into some permission issues, and it sounds like when using xvfb it's running as root (as it's referencing user with id `0`).

How can I get firefox to successfully run?

While logged into a non root user, I'm using `xvfb-run firefox` as the command which is resulting in the following error being constantly displayed in terminal:

> (firefox:14843): dconf-CRITICAL **: 12:15:56.021: unable to create
> directory '/run/user/0/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work
> properly.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Hello. I do not see any version of Ubuntu mentioned in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run gsettings for another user Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134453/how-to-run-gsettings-for-another-user-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)

Comment: It does not, at least not to my understanding. I'm not using sudo.